# Changing the font of a button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I know this question has been asked before, and the question seemed to be solved, but I have an issue that I can't seem to solve. I'm trying to change to font of a UIButton using

`advanceButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont (name: "ArchitectsDaughter", size: 17)`

However, when I use this I get a compile message that

```
(AnyObject) ->() Does not have a member named 'titleLabel'
```

I've tried both the implicit, normal, and optional types for `titleLabel` but nothing will fix this. Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like you either have a method named `advanceButton` that is colliding with a variable named `advanceButton`, or instead of defining an `@IBOutlet` for your button you defined an `@IBAction`.

Comment: Ah it seems your right. Sorry, still very new to this! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

Your advanceButton is not of type UIButton.

When you define advanceButton make sure it is of type UIButton.

like so,

```
var advanceButton : UIButton = UIButton()
advanceButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 25)
```